# What does "fewer and fewer" mean?

Tags: idioms, repetition

What does the idiom "fewer and fewer" mean?

Does it mean *seldom* or *step by step*?

Answer (score 6):

It's not an idiom, because it means exactly what it says. This may be why it's difficult to search for an explanation.

Any repeated word in such an expression (like *step by step*) implies some sort of repetition: a step followed by another and so on. Such expressions indicate a **continuous process.**

So it is with *fewer and fewer:* at one instance there are fewer [of whatever] than before; look again and there are fewer still.

A [random sentence from the internet](http://www.freshplaza.com/article/155611/Much-fewer-Chilean-grapes-to-Europe) has

> But due to the exchange rate, **fewer and fewer** Chilean grapes are coming to Europe.

Over time, the number of grapes exported to Europe is dropping. One year there are fewer than the previous year; the next year, even fewer.